# RewriteCond {REMOTE_ADDR} Not Working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to allow access to two IPs and redirect everyone else, but the IP part is being ignored and redirecting everyone - why isn't this working?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# access for dev
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^208\.48\.253\.17 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^204\.210\.196\.20
RewriteRule ^who-we-are(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/about-us/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://www.newsite.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your first rule will/should redirect anyone without the listed IPs from current domain `who-we-are` to `http://www.newsite.com/about-us/` is that the desired outcome?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^208\.48\.253\.17 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^204\.210\.196\.20
```

In this condition **`[OR]`** is not working and you should leave it...

Answer (score 1):

Please open your httpd.conf file in Apache Conf directory
and then activate at this line **#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**
to remove #(hash) symbol on the left text.

and then restart your web service.

thanks. I hope this helpful